# JQuery advice on moving images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a webpage where you can play the card game concentration on. Part of this page includes the cards sliding to the bottom of the page, and then fading out (if the two cards match).

Since I am using saved images on my computer for the card game, I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to approach this.

I'm guessing the JQuery would have to be an event in itself that occurs only if some if/else logic is met.

What I have so far for the JQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $document.ready(function(){
        $("img").click(function(){
            $("card1").animate({
                down:'100px';
                opacity:'0.0';
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

The "img" would be the local image I have saved on my computer right?

Besides that I'm really unsure how to get the JQuery to happen since there is no button to click to start the animation and it will have to be nested inside the if/else logic that confirms wether the cards match up or not. Would it be some kind of "on..." event? Can you make a jquery code block a function? So it would be easy to call.

Also the jQuery has to move two copies of the same image, which could be anywhere on the webpage, so is there a way to have both move to the bottom of the page, and not just a set amount of pixels?

And can you have events inside of jQuery? Like I want the fadeout to happen once the two images reach the bottom of the page.

All help/advice is very appreciated:))

edit**** Here is the code that I have so far...lots left to do though

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 80%;

        }
    td, th{
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;

    }
    h1{
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Concentration</h1>

        <table border=1 id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th id="1"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="2"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="3"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="4"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="5"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="6"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="7"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="8"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="9"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="10"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="11"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="12"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="13"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="14"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="15"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="16"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="17"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="18"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="19"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="20"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="21"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="22"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="23"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="24"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="25"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="26"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="27"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="28"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="29"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="30"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="31"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="32"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="33"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="34"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="35"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="36"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="37"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="38"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="39"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="40"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="41"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="42"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="43"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="44"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="45"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="46"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="47"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="48"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="49"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="50"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="51"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>
                <th id="52"><img src="./card-BMPs/back.bmp" alt="Mountain View" style="width:71px;height:96px;"></th>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </center>
    <script>
        var amountOfCards = 52;
        var deck[amountOfCards];
        function CreateDeck(){
            deck[0] = new Card() deck[1] = new Card() deck[2] = new Card() deck[3] = new Card() deck[4] = new Card() deck[5] = new Card() deck[6] = new Card() deck[7] = new Card() deck[8] = new Card() deck[9] = new Card() deck[10] = new Card() deck[11] = new Card() deck[12] = new Card() deck[13] = new Card() deck[14] = new Card() deck[15] = new Card() deck[16] = new Card() deck[17] = new Card() deck[18] = new Card() deck[19] = new Card() deck[20] = new Card() deck[21] = new Card() deck[22] = new Card() deck[23] = new Card() deck[24] = new Card() deck[25] = new Card() deck[26] = new Card()
            for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++){
                deck[] = new Card() } deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() deck[0] = new Card() }
    function Card(t, val, id, src)
    {this.id = id;
        this.type = t; this.src =src;
        this.value = val;
        this.flipped = false; }

    function isMatch(card1, card2){
        if(card1.type == card2.type && card1.value == card2.value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function exists(card){ }


    $document.ready(function(){
        $("img").click(function(){
            $("card1").animate({
                down:'100px';
                opacity:'0.0';
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You can call `$("card1").animate({...})` from inside your if/else. Perhaps if you were to [edit] your question to show the relevant code from your game we could advise where to put the `.animate()` call.

Comment: Note that `$("card1")` is looking for a tag `<card1></card1>` and that is probably not what you have. Assuming it is an ID it would be `$('#card1")` but also note ID's must be unique by definition. Show some html

Comment: @nnnnnn What I got so far

Comment: I wonder if the draggable/droppable and related interactions available here: https://jqueryui.com/ would help with this?